# Sending email with PHP from my website

Tags: php, email

i try to send verification mail for registring from my website
the probleme that i had is that the code didn't giving me any error but it not sending any mail this the code:

```html
$connect=mysql_connect('mysql.hostinger.fr','u423178114_user','pass')or die('erreur');
   mysql_select_db('u423178114_gm');
   $reg=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
   $rows=mysql_num_rows($reg);
   if($rows==0)
   {
    $token=rand('19849','98765');
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$fname','$lname','$email','$tele','$username','$password1','$password2','$token','0')");
    $derid=mysql_insert_id();
    //email
    $to=$email;
    $subject="Activation du compte";
    $en_tete="FROM: admin@groupemaghreb.besaba.com";
    $server='mx1.hostinger.fr';
    ini_set('SMTP',$server);
    ini_set('sendmail_from', 'admin@groupemaghreb.besaba.com');
    ini_set('smtp_port', '2525');
    ini_set(auth, true);
    ini_set('username','admin@groupemaghreb.besaba.com');  
    ini_set('password','pass');
    $body="Hello cliquer ici pour activer votre compte
    <a href='http://www.groupemaghreb.besaba.com/site/active.php?id='$derid'&code=$token'></a>";
    error_reporting (E_ALL); 
    ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
    mail($to,$subject,$en_tete,$body);
    if (mail($to,$subject,$en_tete,$body)) {  
    echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");  }
    else {   echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");  }
    //die("Inscription terminé <a href='index.html'> connectez </a> vous");
    //die("Inscription terminén consultez votre email");
    
   }else echo"Ce utilisateur n'est pas disponible";
```

Comment: Are you getting the message "Email successfully sent"?

Comment: Have you confirmed (via echo) the values of `$to`?

Comment: Do get rid of the first call to `mail()`...

Comment: thank you for replay yes i get "Email successfully sent" no i didn't  confirmed (via echo) the values of $to

Comment: i just verified the value of $to it is the email that i want to send a mail. i didn't get what you want to mean by "Do get rid of the first call to mail()"

Comment: Your code looks like this:
`mail($to,$subject,$en_tete,$body);
if (mail($to,$subject,$en_tet,$body)) {`
That is TWO calls to mail. Delete the first line and leave the line beginning with `if`.

Comment: i delete it but i sill didn't get any mail

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to send using port 25 (standard SMTP) rather than 2525.

Comment: no it's 2525 its a port of smtp of my sub domain that i had create by hostlinger. when i test the server and the port by send mail using java it work but in php not